# Uncaught type error number is not a function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i have created the website in MVC4 and Using knockout as well.  I am getting the error Uncaught type error number is not a function in below line of code on Button Click.

```
 var sum = newIdea2[0].TotalImpact() + newIdea2[0].TotalPracticality() + newIdea2[0].TotalAlignment();
```

Below is the Complete line of code:-

```
function SubmitIPAOnClick(data) {

        var ideaId = 0;
        if ($.isNumeric(data.Id)) {
            ideaId = data.Id;
        } else {
            ideaId = data.Id();
        }

        ajaxRequest("post", "/api/IdeaAPI/UpdateIPA/" + (ideaId || "") + "/" + (loginUserId || ""), data, null)
         .done(function (result) {

             var newIdea2 = [result];

             //var ideaCount = 0;
             //ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.ideas(), function (newIdea) {
             //    if (ideaId == newIdea.Id()) {
             //        self.ideas.replace(self.ideas()[ideaCount], new Idea(newIdea2[0]))
             //    }
             //    ideaCount++;
             //});


             var idea = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.ideas(), function (currentIdea) {

                 return currentIdea.Id() == ideaId;

             });

             if (idea) {
                 idea.MyAlignment(newIdea2[0].MyAlignment);
                 idea.MyImpact(newIdea2[0].MyImpact);
                 idea.MyPracticality(newIdea2[0].MyPracticality);
                 idea.TotalAlignment(newIdea2[0].TotalAlignment);
                 idea.TotalImpact(newIdea2[0].TotalImpact);
                 idea.TotalPracticality(newIdea2[0].TotalPracticality);
                 var avg = ko.computed(function () {

                     var sum = newIdea2[0].TotalImpact() + newIdea2[0].TotalPracticality() + newIdea2[0].TotalAlignment();

                     if (sum > 0) {

                         return Math.round((sum / 3) * 10) / 10;
                     }
                     else {
                         return 0;
                     }
                 }).extend({ notify: 'always' });


                 idea.Average(avg);
             }


         })
         .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
             console.log("Request Failed" + textStatus + "," + error + ",," + jqxhr.toString());
         });
    }
    self.SubmitIPA = function (data, event) {

        var $this = $(event.target);

        SubmitIPAOnClick(data);
        HideRatingsSection2($this);
 };
    self.SearchIdeas = function (data) {
        var searchText = $("#txtSearchIdeas").val().toLowerCase();

        var SearchSucessString = "";

        var appendString = "";

        var goalFound = false;
        var userFound = false;
        var ideaTitleFound = false;
        var goalTagsFound = false;

 for (var ideaCount = 0; ideaCount < self.ideas().length; ideaCount++) {
            var tempIdea = self.ideas()[ideaCount];
            if (searchText == "") {
                tempIdea.ShowThisIdea(true);
            } else if (tempIdea.GoalName().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
                goalFound = true;
                tempIdea.ShowThisIdea(true);
            } else if (tempIdea.FullName().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
                userFound = true;
                tempIdea.ShowThisIdea(true);
            } else if (tempIdea.Goal().Tags.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
                goalTagsFound = true;
                tempIdea.ShowThisIdea(true);
            } else if (tempIdea.Title().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
                ideaTitleFound = true;
                tempIdea.ShowThisIdea(true);
            }
            else {
                tempIdea.ShowThisIdea(false);
            }
        }
```

Please let me know whats the solution of this problem as i am trying to get it resolve.

Comment: You should use `idea` instead of `newidea` : `var sum = idea.TotalImpact() + idea.TotalPracticality() + idea.TotalAlignment();` and `idea.Average(avg);` should be `idea.Average = avg;`

Comment: After using idea i am getting the error that it is not defined.